Flutter iOS Firebase logs no longer printing for App Attest
I have a problem with a project that used to print out the Firebase logs and I was able to collect the App Attest debug token. This is not a problem on Android, it prints out every log that it is supposed to.
I haven't touched the project for a few months but since then iOS 18 has come out which I suspect plays a role in this but I can't find any evidence.
My Flutter setup is as such:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 15.0.1 24A348 darwin-x64, locale en-AU)
    • Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at /Users/haydenyoung/DevTools/Flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2663184aa7 (6 weeks ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
    • Engine revision 36335019a8
    • Dart version 3.5.3
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

My dependencies in the pubspec.yaml include the following:
  firebase_analytics: ^11.3.3
  firebase_app_check: ^0.3.1+3
  firebase_core: ^3.6.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^4.1.3
  firebase_performance: ^0.10.0+8
  firebase_messaging: ^15.1.3
  firebase_remote_config: ^5.1.3

My current code to setup Firebase is
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
        webProvider: ReCaptchaV3Provider('recaptcha-v3-site-key'),
        androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,
        appleProvider: AppleProvider.debug,
      );

I've deleted the podlock file, the Pods folder, the pubspec.lock, Flutter clean, pub get, pub update, pub outdated
I have the -FIRDebugEnabled flag in the Arguments Passed On Launch in the Scheme for the Run Debug in my iOS app.
I have created a new project, given the same bundle id and the same GoogleService-Info and it also had the same problem
I've tried downgrading the dependencies to what they were when everything was working only to be met with compile errors.
I added
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <false/>

to the info.plist
I've used a simulator using iOS 18 and iOS 17, I've used a device running iOS 17.
App Attest is still enabled on the relevant Certificates which are associated with the relevant Provisioning Profiles
None of these things have changed the fact that Firebase isn't logging to the console
